# nginx change root on specific url

Tags: php, nginx

I have one nginx http server configuration like this:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name test.loc;
root /var/www/test;

location ~ \.php {
  fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.+)$;
  set $fsn /index.php;
  if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name){
      set $fsn $fastcgi_script_name;
  }

fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
include fastcgi_params;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fsn;
fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO        $fastcgi_path_info;
fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fsn;
fastcgi_read_timeout 180;               
}

location / {
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

location /sample/ {
    root /var/www/test2/;
}
}
```

I want to address `http://test.loc/sample` root was in the folder `/var/www/test2` but no matter how I tried, displays the contents of `/var/www/test`.

Thank you in advance.

UPD:

now i have this config:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name test.loc;
root /var/www/test;

error_log /var/log/nginx/mytest.log;
index index.html index.php;

location / {

index index.html index.php;
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
set $root /var/www/test;


}

location /sample {

    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    alias /var/www/test2;

    location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
  #try_files $uri =404;
  #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  #fastcgi_split_path_info  ^(.+\.php)(.+)$;

  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
}

}
```

all works fine, but when i get content of this url `http://test.loc/sample/` i see content `/var/www/test2/sample/index.php`.
I would like to be displayed `/var/www/test2/index.php`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: try removing the trailing slash from `location /sample/` and reload nginx, or if you have a file inside `/sample` try it, for example `http://test.loc/sample/index.html` does it work?

Comment: i remove the trailing slash.
http://test.loc/sample - error404
http://test.loc/sample/index.php -content of /var/www/test/index.php

Don't work :(

Comment: and did it work or not ?

Comment: don't work, http://test.loc/sample/index.php must be display content /var/www/test2/index.php

Comment: I think it will be better with a slash http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root

Comment: The reason the slash is added is so that `location /sample` doesn't match `location /sample2`, just wanted to make sure it's not missing the location because of the slash.